# VEC model: EViews differences variables authomatically

Tags: vector-error-correction-model, eviews

I am performing a multivariate time series analysis. My variables are stationary at level. Whenever I want to make a VEC model, but EViews will difference the data authomatically. What can I do about it so that my model won't be differenced?

Comment: How is the progress? Was the answer helpful?

Comment: I am wondering if the answer is satisfactory or whether it needs some elaboration. FYI, satisfactory answers may be accepted by clicking on the tick mark to the left; this is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are stationary at level, then VECM is not an appropriate model for them. VECM should be used for integrated variables that are cointegrated. For stationary data, use a VAR model instead.